# Including PHP file/s with AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to use AJAX to include a language PHP file each time someone clicks on a certain button, so I created two inputs with a submit method:

```
<input type="submit" id="spanish" name="es" value="Spanish"/><br>
<input type="submit" id="english" name="en" value="English"/>
```

Then I'm using a jQuery script to establish an AJAX request to the server:

```
<script>

  $('#spanish').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
      url: "init.php",
      type: "POST"
    })
  })
  $('#english').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
      url: "init.php",
      type: "POST"
    })
  })

</script>
```

I want to pass the input values to the PHP function I created in in `init.php` through an AJAX request:

```
if (($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] === "POST") && (isset($_POST['es']))) {
    include $lang . 'spanish.php';
} elseif (($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] === "POST") && (isset($_POST['en']))) {
    include $lang . 'english.php';
} else {
    include $lang . 'english.php';
}
```

Also, I don't know how to use the `success()` or `done()` methods in this situation. There is no values or data returned I suppose! I am a little confused with AJAX because it's the first time I've needed to use it.

UPDATE: 
@Sacha No it's not appending like adding something new. in my page I'm using a language function for each word or paragraph I want the meaning of it in the determined language. For example in my website there is a tab called"About Us", to translate this tab to an equivalent meaning in another language I'm calling the function of language inside that tab , in my PHP English file I already created a function called lang:

```
function lang( $phrase ) {
static $lang = array(
'HOME'             => 'Home',
'CATEGORIES'       => 'Our Services',
'CONTACT'          => 'Contact Us',
'TEAM'             => 'Our Team',
'ABOUT'            => 'About Us',
'WELCOME'          => 'You are welcome',
'WELCOME_MESSAGE'  => 'Your are welcome',
'LANGUAGE'         => 'English')
 return $lang[$phrase];}
```

Also for Spanish language I have the same file with the same function but for my Spanish words and sentences. one of those files I need to include when someone clicks on a specific button. That's what I need from the Ajax script to achieve for me. Hope this comment explains enough.

Another UPDATE: 
Thank you again @Sacha :D. Actually I already tried this and it worked perfectly with language files including, but what I also using this buttons for is to change my theme CSS file and replace it with another CSS directory by using a simple jQuery script. The problem is that when the button been clicked, the page reloads because of the POST, GET methods and the style file never changes. That's why I need AJAX to include my PHP file, then I can avoid page reloading operation.

Answer (score 0):

You could use GETs and make this a bit easier ..

```
<script>

  $('#spanish').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
      url: "init.php?lang=es",
      type: "GET"
    })
  })
  $('#english').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
      url: "init.php?lang=en",
      type: "GET"
    })
  })

</script>
```

And then

```
if (($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] === "GET") && (isset($_GET['es']))) {
    include $lang . 'spanish.php';
} elseif (($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] === "GET") && (isset($_GET['en']))) {
    include $lang . 'english.php';
} else {
    include $lang . 'english.php';
}
```

There is probably a neater way to achieve the same result but my suggestion is very similar to your approach.

By the way, I assume this is just a snippet of your code as in itself it won't do much. You can read about how to use done() at http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Sorry, no, the GET parameter would be called`lang` in that case, which actually allows for a much more elegant `switch` statement. No GET parameters `es` or `en` will ever be set with that code...

Comment: I've already tried GET but didn't work out, Thank you. @Chris

Comment: Would you suggest a hint about some solution please ?@arkascha

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this problem is really simple, first off you'll need the buttons:

```
<button type="button" id="spanish" name="es" >Spanish</button><br>
<button type="button" id="english" name="en" >English</button>
```

Then, you won't need any ajax nor submits, just this:

```
$('#spanish').click(function(){
  window.location.href = window.location.host + "/init.php&lang=es";
});
$('#english').click(function(){
  window.location.href = window.location.host + "/init.php&lang=es";
});
```

This will make the buttons reload the page, sending the query string.

And then you must PREPEND this to the init.php:

```
if (($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] === "GET") && isset($_GET['lang']) && $_GET['lang'] == "en" ) {
    include $lang . 'spanish.php';
} elseif (($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] === "GET") && isset($_GET['lang']) && $_GET['lang'] == "en") {
    include $lang . 'english.php';
} else {
    include $lang . 'english.php';
}
```

Remember, we are using get and not post.

Comment: Thaks for your kindly respond. Actually I want to include a php language file with the script, so I'm not sure how to handle the output! @sacha

Comment: The include statement in php makes the server run a srcript, so when you write `include $lang . 'english.php';` the server is going to run the english script. what I don't know is what do you mean by "include". Do you want to append something to the webpage?

Comment: I've just updated the main question post, hope this update will make the question more clear.@Sacha

Comment: Oooh, I get what you are trying to do, let me edit the answer because it'll be much different now.

Comment: Thank you again @Sacha :D. Actually I already tried this and it worked perfectly with language files including, but what I also using this buttons for is to change my theme CSS file and replace it with another CSS directory by using a simple jQuery script. The problem is that when the button been clicked, the page reloads because of the POST, GET methods and the style file never changes. That's why I need AJAX to include my PHP file, then I can avoid page reloading operation.

Comment: There's plenty of way's you can do that, here's a couple:
You can make the phpfile also have a variable with the path of the css file.
You can have the javascript perform a replace on every word.

Comment: Oh It's worked! Unbelievable! I'd never think about the solution without using a jQuery script ! Thank you so much @Sacha

Answer (score 0):

In short, ajax can't interact with the PHP of the page it's running *from*, because that code has already been run. As such, you can't include a PHP file with ajax, but you can send your data to an external PHP script for processing, and update the current page with the results returned.

By the sounds of it you don't need that though and would get away with a simple redirect as seems to be working for you elsewhere. This is a simple way to do that, and you can always adjust it to use an AJAX function rather than redirect.

**HTML**

If you give all of your buttons a class and use data-tags you only need one click function.

```
<button class='submitButtons' data-lang='en'>English</button>
<button class='submitButtons' data-lang='es'>Spanish</button>
<button class='submitButtons' data-lang='it'>Italian</button>
etc...
```

**jQuery**

```
$(".submitButtons").click(function(){
    var langClicked = $(this).data("lang");
    window.location.href = window.location.href + "/init.php?lang=" + langClicked;
}
```

**PHP**  --  *init.php*

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['lang'])){
    $langPath = "/path/to/included/files/dir/";
    $lang = trim($_REQUEST['lang']);             // any other cleanup here
    $ext = ".php";                            // file extension

    $fullPath = $langPath . $lang . $ext;

    if(file_exists($fullPath)){ 
        include $fullPath;
    }
}
```

So the name of your included files will be whatever you've put in the data-lang attribute plus your file extension, e.g. 'en.php', 'es.php'